# Set property value based on condition in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I searched through several questions at Stack Overflow, but nothing helped me. The problem is:

I look in the registry for some value (I know how to do that). I know how to set property. But I cannot find the way how to write this expression in WiX. This is what I want to write in pseudocode:

```
if(registryvalue contains substring1)
    set property to value1
if(registryvalue contains substring2)
    set property to value2
```

This condition must be evaluated at runtime. Is there a way to write this condition? What would some sample code look like?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [type 51 custom action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/custom-action-type-51) to set the property:

```
<CustomAction Id="SET_VALUE1" Property="TEST_PROPERTY" Value="value1" />
<CustomAction Id="SET_VALUE2" Property="TEST_PROPERTY" Value="value2" />
```

Use the condition when you call the custom action in install sequences:

```
 <Custom Action="SET_VALUE1" After="AppSearch">Not Installed AND (REG_VALUE="substring1")</Custom>
 <Custom Action="SET_VALUE2" After="AppSearch">Not Installed AND (REG_VALUE="substring2")</Custom>
```

Or you can write the custom actions in managed code like C#, and schedule it after **AppSearch** in case you have many comparisons.